# What does this prefix mean in front of my C# function

Tags: c#, xslt

What does **str:** prefix mean? It's right in front of mycsharpextmethod

```
<xsl:template name="name1">
        <xsl:param name="text" select="." />
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="str:mycsharpextmethod($text)" />
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the whole document, I would guess that it is a namespace reference (so as to avoid conflicts with any other methods named `mycsharpextmethod`). From the [`W3 Namespaces in XML 1.0 Spec`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-qualnames) (emphasis mine):

> In XML documents conforming to this specification, some names
>   (constructs corresponding to the nonterminal Name) MUST be given as
>   qualified names...**The Prefix provides the namespace prefix part of the
>   qualified name, and MUST be associated with a namespace URI reference
>   in a namespace declaration.** The LocalPart provides the
>   local part of the qualified name.

As an (slightly unrelated) example, the [`EXSLT String Library`](http://www.exslt.org/str/) uses the `str:` prefix to properly namespace any string-related functions.

Comment: @CodeCaster - that isn't correct. The `select` attribute of an `<xsl:value-of>` element is perfectly capable of handling a namespace reference as part of its value.

Comment: I can only find that the `select` attribute must contain an [expression](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#prod-xpath30-Expr), which makes no mention of namespaces. But I'm no expert in the XSLT field so I retracted my comment, perhaps I'm overseeing something, because for example in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/284145/266143) it is mentioned.

Comment: @CodeCaster - take a look at this SO question/answer for some more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585533/xsl-and-namespaces